# When to use CustomJsUrl

Tags: sharepoint-2013

When is [CustomJsUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.customjavascriptfileurl.aspx) supposed to be used.

Is there any reason to use it rather than `<script src=''>`?